# Listener called when view loads

Tags: android, ios, oncreate, rating

I have an android rating bar that I have implemented. And in my `onCreate` I have

```
 mRatingBar = (RatingBar)findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);
    mRatingBar.setRating(0);
```

Then in `onCreate` I add on on click listener like this

```
mRatingBar.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, final float rating, boolean fromUser) {
```

But then all my code inside this method gets called everytime the view loads. I only want this to be called when the user taps to change the star ratings, why is it being called everytime. I know it is in onCreate but I though it would still only be called when the bar it tapped by the user?

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Did you call `setRating()` before `setOnRatingBarChangeListener()`?

Comment: @LawrenceChoy yes I did. Is that why?